# Could anyone explain the grammatical structure of a sentence 僕の螺旋 ただならぬ手を繋ごうとしてる

Tags: verbs, song-lyrics, grammar, volitional-form

Trying to understand the lyrics of Granrodeo song 君に One Way Love, I'm struggling to grasp how 僕の螺旋
ただならぬ手を繋ごうとしてる can mean "my spiral has my hands all tied up" (translation i found here https://yokuboumugendai.com/2017/05/22/translation-%E5%90%9B%E3%81%AB-one-way-love/).Could anyone elucidate the sentence structure, especially in part of using volitional form 繋ごう with としてる ? Or maybe if translation isn't correct, could anyone fix it? Thanks for any help

Comment: To me this sounds like he's saying something about trying to join his snarled hands, as if he's considering something about himself in old age.  But, I'm bad of making sense of lyrics in English let alone Japanese.

Comment: i think i meant gnarled and not snarled. lol

Comment: @A.Ellet Thank you very much! Well, lyrics are always a pain, but that's the reason I love them so much (kinda masochistic of me)